# Make bot send a message that looks like it was sent from another user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I've seen on some server that a bot can send messages and appear like he's another user, and when you try to click on the profile of the user who sent the message, it shows that another user sent it (Not even the bot who sends the original message, but the server owner, the bot is called [UnbeliveaBoat](https://unbelievaboat.com/)). How could I do something like this? I've attached an image to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to achieve what's in the image I've attached, you do it via WebHooks.
You create a webhook on your server and set it to whatever channel you want, then make your own bot post to the webhook and override the username and avatar.

https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks
https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook

Comment: You create a webhook and post to it, overriding the user & avatar picture to make it look like another user.

Comment: It points to the webhook bot, I've tested it

Comment: Oh, apologies, I missinterpreted ypur wanted results ...